Youtube IFrame - Cache Embed Video For React App Performance Optimization
Using Youtube IFrame Embed.
When we switch pages back and forth, the component is remounted. I see it loads the iFrame again making a lot of network calls and slowing down the performance.
What is the best approch for performance enhancement ? 
I can think of keeping the embed div hidden in the parent but looking for some better approach here.
Thanks.
